# how to delete multiple records from a table (getting multiple values in input)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to delete multiple records from table at the same time.

Sample input:

```
{"INPUT":{"ID":"2200038,2200039,2200073,2200019"}}
```

Input will be provided from the application i.e.,

ID can be random - it gets changed based on requirements.

```
delete from mytable
where id = ....?
```

I want to delete multiple ID's coming from the input at the same time.

Comment: delete from yourtable where id IN (1,2,3)

Comment: Where will you be creating this query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract the ids from your json string as an array and delete those using `ANY` operator

```
WITH t AS 
( 
  SELECT '{"INPUT":{"ID":"2200038,2200039,2200073,2200019"}}' AS input 
) 
DELETE FROM   mytable 
   WHERE  id = ANY ( SELECT unnest(
                          String_to_array(input::json->'INPUT'->>'ID',',')::int[]) 
                  FROM   t );
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=9a29245eac11271291f3d7a134aa60a1)

Here's a demo using a Bind variable for input in psql. Note that `UNNEST` was not needed here.

```
\set input '{"INPUT":{"ID":"2200038,2200039,2200073,2200019"}}'
knayak=# DELETE FROM  mytable WHERE
          id = ANY( String_to_array(:'input'::json->'INPUT'->>'ID',',')::int[] )
DELETE 2
```

Answer (score 2):

To delete multiple rows at once with different IDs, one approach is to use `IN`:

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE ID IN (2200038,2200039,2200073,2200019)
```

Here's some documentation and further examples: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-in/

Comment: i cannot hard code any id... it will get changed randomly

Comment: @adams I'm just demonstrating the principle in SQL - since you seemed to be talking about = , I thought maybe you didn't know about IN. How are you constructing your DELETE query? You've shown us some sample input data - where is that coming from? Is it in an application which must build a query? Or as an input parameter to some stored procedure? It appears to be some (poorly structured) JSON but apart from that I've got no context about it. If you want a more precise answer you'll have to give more precise details about your situation. I suggest you edit the question to provide more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some dynamic sql will help

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
const char *stmt = "DELETE FROM tablename WHERE ID IN(?);";

EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;

EXEC SQL PREPARE mystmt FROM :stmt;
inputdata varchar; -- remove unwanted parts of the string

EXEC SQL EXECUTE mystmt USING inputdata;
```

Comment: Nice, but unfortunately your code is for the wrong DBMS...check the tags on the question

Comment: Yikes, sorry dude! I updated my suggestion sans the string replacement